How to add Gpay,apple pay button in every product details page and checkout page using paypal braintree?
I have the Braintree option enabled for payments, and I can see the Apple Pay and Google Pay buttons available. How do I enable these buttons on the following pages:
Product details page
Mini cart
Cart
Checkout page

Please follow the given steps :

Navigate to Store -> Configuration -> Sales -> Payment Methods -> Paypal Braintree.
Configure Paypal Braintree settings.
Enable Apple Pay.
Click the Catalog Product Page tab and select 'Yes' to display Apple Pay on the product detail page.
Click the Checkout Cart Page and select Yes to Display Apple Pay in Minicart and Cart page.

